# How to reenable the old android google translate feature to translate everything on screen?

Tags: home-button, google-translate

Few years ago on my android was possible keeping pressed the home button, to activate a feature that would allow to translate everything on screen. Unfortunately in a subsequent update google decided to replace that awesome functionality with the useless google assistant. Do you know how I can do to get that back? I know it is possible to update screenshots but that it is a way more cumbersome process.

Comment: Note: this feature was available 5 years ago in [Now on Tap](https://blog.google/products/search/more-on-tap-translate-discover-and/) (when Google Assistant was still [Google Now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Now)).